Unable to locate the shadow dom element
I am trying to locate the element which is under the shadow root. however when I accessed one component which is under the SLOT tag and it returned the NONE.
Below are the code.
js_script = """
return (
    document.querySelector("macroponent-f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010").shadowRoot.querySelector(
        "#item-snCanvasAppshellMain").shadowRoot.querySelector(
            "macroponent-76a83a645b122010b913030a1d81c780").shadowRoot.querySelector(
                "sn-canvas-main").shadowRoot.querySelector(
                    "sn-canvas-screen").shadowRoot.querySelector("macroponent-d4d3a42dc7202010099a308dc7c2602b")
);
"""


shadow_root61 = d.execute_script(js_script)
print(shadow_root61)

shadow_root61 returned NONE
Can anyone will help here


If you are using a newer/newest version of Selenium, they've made working with shadow-roots much simpler. Here's a code sample to get you started with the new syntax.
driver.get(url)

shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'shadow_host')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_content = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, 'shadow_content')

assert shadow_content.text == 'some text'

